# Calculating Annuity Payments

Tags: sequences-and-series, actuarial-science

> - A man turns $40$ today and wishes to provide supplemental retirement income of $3000$ at the beginning of each month starting on his $65$-th birthday.
> - Starting today, he makes monthly contributions of $X$ to a fund for $25$ years.
> - The fund earns an annual nominal interest rate of $8 \%$ compounded monthly.
> - On his $65$-th birthday, each $1000$ of the fund will provide $9.65$ of income at the beginning of each month starting immediately and continuing as long as he survives.
> - Calculate $X$.

Hi, does any one understand the last statement regarding how each $\$\ 1000$ funds $\$\ 9.65$ of the income ?. The expression is going to look something like this:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{300} X\,\left(1 + {.08 \over12}\right)^{k}\ =\  ???
\end{align}

Now, the other half is supposed to be the present value of the monthly incomes.  Is the last statement saying that the annuity can sustain itself forever ?.  If that's not the case, then the payments must end at some point
( his death ), but I don't see how we can determine the duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cash flow of payments into the fund is finite.  The cash flow of income paid by the fund is not; it is a perpetuity because it must be sustaining for as long as he survives.

In actuarial notation, we have $$X \ddot s_{\overline{300}\rceil j} = 3000 \ddot a_{\overline{\infty}\rceil k},$$ where $j = i^{(12)}/12 = 0.08/12$, and $k = 9.65/1000 = 0.00965$.  This equation of value is written with respect to the time of the first receipt of income from the fund.  Since $$\ddot s_{\overline{n}\rceil j} = (1+j) \frac{(1+j)^n - 1}{j}, \\ \ddot a_{\overline{\infty}\rceil k} = 1 + \frac{1}{k},$$ it follows that $$X = 3000 \cdot \frac{104.627}{957.367} = 327.858\ldots.$$

Comment: Hi, can you kindly explain why you have $k = 9.65/1000$?  I don't see how that statement about how each $ \$1000$ provides for $ \$9.65$ turns into a rate.

Comment: @AndyTam The phrase "Each 1000 of the fund will provide 9.65 of income at the beginning of each month..." suggests that if the accumulated value of the fund is some dollar amount $Y$, then it will pay out $$\frac{9.65}{1000}Y$$ in income at the beginning of each month, indefinitely, such that it will never deplete the principal.  That in turn suggests we are dealing with a cash flow situation that is analogous to a perpetuity-due with a monthly interest rate of $9.65/1000$.

Comment: @heropup Unless there is a typographical error in SOA's solution manual, your solution is incorrect, unfortunately. Out of the option choices $324.70$ and $328.10$, the correct choice is $324.70$. Could you please clarify what's causing this discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

By GP sum,

$$X(1+\frac{8\%}{12})\frac{1-(1+\frac{8\%}{12})^{300}}{1-(1+\frac{8\%}{12})}=\frac{3000}{1-(1+\frac{9.65}{1000})^{-1}}$$

then

$X=327.8586$

However, if the question is amended to "...supplemental retirement income of 3000 at the **END** of each month starting on his 65-th birthday...", then 324.70 would be correct.

i.e.

$$X(1+\frac{8\%}{12})\frac{1-(1+\frac{8\%}{12})^{300}}{1-(1+\frac{8\%}{12})}=\frac{\frac{3000}{1+\frac{9.65}{1000}}}{1-(1+\frac{9.65}{1000})^{-1}}$$

or

$X=327.8586(1+\frac{9.65}{1000})^{-1}=324.725$

Comment: This should be added as a comment, or edit this answer to make it more detailed.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for your comment.
I have added more details to my answer.
As this is the first time I join this forum, I am still exploring the functions provided in this website. I hope I would make a better answer next time.